# How to get Steam games that I haven't bought to show up on my library?

Tags: steam

Crazy question, I know. And no, this is *not* "how 2 get steam gaems for free", I fully expect them to show up with a "Buy Now" button (or something of the sorts) instead of the usual "Play" one.
Simply adding all the files to my "common" folder doesn't do anything. Where, perhaps, does Steam store the data of what games are installed for me?

Comment: I doubt it's supported in the app itself. But I agree it would be a nice thing to have.

Comment: I don't think you can. There's still the wishlist, though.

Comment: It is supported. I had a few of those before I wiped my hard drive. For example as leftovers from free weekends. Or for my current purpose, from Family sharing.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a game you already own to show up in your library? If you want to do that you just go up to the Games tab on the top and go to the bottom option, "Add a Non-Steam Game to My Library", then finding the .exe or the shortcut on your desktop and clicking on that. From then on when you use that shortcut or .exe you will be shown "playing" it on steam.

Comment: No, I am asking how to make a game that is on Steam, but that I haven't bought (and thus don't own) to show up on my Steam library.

Comment: Why? What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? What's your end goal? Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you might have better options.

Comment: @Michaellogg is right, this could very well be an instance of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yes, well, I'm afraid that would just produce more incorrect and off-topic answers.  
I'm trying to get Family Sharing to work without having to log on to my computer with two separate accounts.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you tell us what your root problem is, instead of how you're trying to solve it.  As it stands, this seems like a very tortured solution.  If you're trying to get Steam Family Sharing, tell us exactly what it is you want to work.

Comment: I did. I want to get Steam Family Sharing to work. I want to play games from someone else's account with their consent, but without them logging onto my computer.

Comment: Wait. If family sharing is already active, the games _should automaticly_ be in your library. If it's _not active_ (or not connected to your account, or what ever the current set up is), you're basicly trying to "activate Falmily Sharing" without activating family sharing. Something I'm pretty sure Steam seeks to _avoid_.

Comment: Steam "forgets" and doesn't automatically check unless I try to play one of those games. My friend has already authorized my computer, but Steam never bothered to check if it was authorized. If I could have one of my friend's games on my library, Steam would check if I had permission to play it, then allow me, and display all other games from them as well. I am stuck at the part where I can't get steam to recognize that I am authorized, because none of my friend's games are installed for me.

Comment: *I want to play games from someone else's account with their consent, but without them logging onto my computer.* (nope) : "To enable the sharing feature, **you must first log in to your family member or friend's computer with your Steam account**. Next, open the settings menu, click on the Family tab, and choose to authorize the computer. You will then have the option to authorize any accounts that have also logged into the same computer."

Comment: Well, yes, that's what they want you to believe, it's obviously possible, the question is just "how?"

Comment: OK. Let me see if I can get this straight. You had Family Sharing. You used it and downloaded a few games. Steam 'forgot' the Family Sharing. The game files are still on your harddrive, but aren't in your library. You want them in your library. Am I even close? (Also, the comment thread is getting really long. You should propably write what we've discovered here into your question, for the benefit of new people trying to figure this out.)

Comment: I had family sharing. Then I did a clean reinstall. Now I don't have family sharing because I don't have any extra games. Also, yes, I copied the files back to my Steam folder, but they're not going into my library.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this can't be done.

It's seems that Family Sharing authentication isn't given to a Steam-account, but to a "machine". And a different Steam installation (as well as a *resintall*) counts as a **"new" machine**, as far as Steam is concerned.

As such, the reinstall has wiped out the Family Sharing authentication that your friend has given earlier. Steam is actively ignoring the files you copied, because it no longer thinks you have an authentication to play the games.

I'm afraid that the only solution is to have your friend somehow re-authenticate your "new machine" through Family Sharing. Yes, this means somehow getting him in front of your computer again.

Source: https://steamcommunity.com/groups/familysharing/discussions/1/540738051790971117/

Comment: While not entirely false, and after investigating the matter, I feel this will be the way I'll try to solve the issue, I'd still like to point out that Steam doesn't check every time you open your library whether you're authorized to play or not.

Comment: It checks only when you actually try to launch the game, otherwise I believe the information is stored somewhere on your computer, and it decides based on that whether to: a) display the game in your library at all, b) display a "Play" button, c) display a button with some other text. In the 2 latter cases, it checks whether your account and PC are authorized, and if not, asks if you want to send your friend a request for authorization.

Comment: @Torn You seem a bit stuck on the notion of making games "appear" in the Library. Sure, there may be a way to hack Steam-files to make it so (at least temporarily), but I doubt it'll be very easy and I doubt even more it will be _any help_.

Comment: Oh, it's surely possible, but it does seem Steam hasn't made it easy. Why wouldn't it be of any help though? If the games were in my library, I could ask for authorization without them accessing my computer. Regardless, this issue has been solved in another method.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this whole feature is contained in Wishlist, where you can store games you would like, and be able to return to them any time. And it can warn you by e-mail, where there is discount for them and so.

Try it, it is under Shop button, and it is fully designed for bookmarking the games you would like to have.

For Library, I doubt that it will be possible, just because it would do the same as mentioned Wishlist feature. :)

Comment: You are mistaken. I am aware of the wishlist, and use it extensively. I had unplayable games in my library before I wiped my hard drive. These are sometimes left over from free weekends or from Family Sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Free games will only show up in the library if you have downloaded a DLC for them.
For example Team Fortress 2 will show up in your library if you have bought premium account (because it counts as a DLC), however Path of Exile will not show up as there's no DLC for it.